# Using SES java sdk in spring boot (gradle) project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to use AWS SES in my spring boot project.
I found the Java SDK package name, and below is my code for it.
(I am already using S3, just trying to add SES.)

```
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.901')
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:1.11.901')
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.901')
```

And below is my external library list about aws sdk.

[image: External Library picture]

I was expecting to see `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:1.11.901`, but instead I am seeing
`com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-kms:1.11.901`.

The versions of all the Amazon java sdks added to my project is the same, `1.11.901`.

Any suggestions about why this is happening??

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you port your code to version 2 of the AWS SDK for Java. For V2 and Gradle, see this doc for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html